# ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement- when run a package in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, oracle12c, ora-00900

I am using Oracle 12c database and trying to run a package using SQL commands.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "PK_CP_OTM" as
FUNCTION F_CP_OPTIMIZATION (
     v_current_day IN VARCHAR2,
     v_branch_code IN VARCHAR2)
     RETURN VARCHAR2;
END PK_CP_OTM;
```

When I try to execute it using:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE PK_CP_OTM.F_CP_OPTIMIZATION('20190409','BRNCD001');
END;
```

It shows:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 3
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Littlefoot said, you don't need dynamic SQL here, you can make a static call; but as you are calling a function you do need somewhere to put the result of the call:

```
declare
  l_result varchar2(30); -- make it a suitable size 
begin
  l_result := pk_cp_otm.f_cp_optimization('20190409','BRNCD001');
end;
/
```

In SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and SQLcl you can use the `execute` client command (which might have caused some confusion) and a bind variable for the result:

```
var result varchar2(30);

exec :result := pk_cp_otm.f_cp_optimization('20190409','BRNCD001');

print result
```

Comment: yeah, both dynamics and static calling are working fine, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing dynamic here, so - why would you use dynamic SQL at all?

Anyway: if you insist, then you'll have to *select* the function *into* something (e.g. a local variable). Here's an example

First, the package:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> create or replace package pk_cp_otm
  2  as
  3     function f_cp_optimization (v_current_day  in varchar2,
  4                                 v_branch_code  in varchar2)
  5        return varchar2;
  6  end pk_cp_otm;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pk_cp_otm
  2  as
  3     function f_cp_optimization (v_current_day  in varchar2,
  4                                 v_branch_code  in varchar2)
  5        return varchar2
  6     is
  7     begin
  8        return 'Littlefoot';
  9     end;
 10  end pk_cp_otm;
 11  /

Package body created.
```

How to call the function?

```
SQL> declare
  2     l_result  varchar2 (20);
  3  begin
  4     execute immediate
  5        'select pk_cp_otm.f_cp_optimization (''1'', ''2'') from dual'
  6        into l_result;
  7
  8     dbms_output.put_line ('result = ' || l_result);
  9  end;
 10  /
result = Littlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: yeah, both dynamics and static calling are working fine, many thanks!